# svn delete - returns No write-lock error (TortoiseSVN 1.7.6)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to delete the folder `D:\SVN_HOME\EclipseWorkspace\MF_CENTER_INFO` from svn.

Right click on the folder => TortoiseSVN => Delete => Yes to all

This returns the error: No Write-lock in D:\SVN_HOME\EclipseWorkspace

[image: tortoisesvn error message: No Write-lock in D:\SVN_HOME\EclipseWorkspace]

How can I fix this?

Comment: In my case, the error was overcome by calling `svn cleanup`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do a SVN-rename (not regular rename), commit, then you can do a SVN-delete successfully. I tried doing a regular rename first and renamed back to the original name, but still received the error when trying to delete the folder.

Answer (score 1):

For me this problem was fixed by deactivating the indexing service. Renaming the folder may have a similar effect.

Answer (score 1):

svn-Delete the content of the folder first, svn-rename the folder, svn-undo the add of the renamed folder. And commit...gone was the folder :) ... Maybe deleting the content was unnecessary, but I got rid of the error and the folder was deleted. Hope this still helps after so long

Answer (score 0):

Try again deleting the folder in the Repo browser. Don't forget to refresh the Repo browser view (F5 key) to see if it is really gone and update your workspace

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused when you try to commit on deleting from windows explorer.
In fact you should delete as below:

Right click on folder->Tortoise SVN->Delete
Next on explorer on empty space
Right click->Tortoise SVN->Check for modification   (and verify your change)
Next commit